# How to return month short form from date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, monthcalendar

I am using this code

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE()) AS 'Month Name'
```

to get the month name. But how can I limit the name of the month up to 3 characters only? Example is `FEB` in this month.

Comment: SQL does not support returning short names so I guess you'll have to stick to something like `select SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, GETDATE()),1 , 3) AS 'Month Name'`

Comment: Things like this are usually best left to your UI code.  Unless of course this is a purely academic exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server, you can use the `SUBSTRING` function, i.e.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(DATENAME(month, GETDATE()), 1, 3) AS 'Month Name'
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SQL server:

```
Select FORMAT(getdate(),'MMM') as shortMonthName
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your date in format "FEB" you can try

```
Select LEFT(UPPER(DATENAME(MM, Getdate())),3)
```